# How to send followup message in Slack App using slack_bolt?

Tags: python, chatbot, slack, slack-api, slack-bolt

I am building a bot that will answer a question asked in a slack App.

I want to configure a followup question

*Note: Yes and No are radio buttons*

eg.

```
User: What is the event date?
Bot: 22nd Feb, 2023
(after the answer bot will trigger followup question with radio buttons)
Bot: Does this answer your query?
 - Yes
 - No
```

Here's my code

```
import asyncio
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode.async_handler import AsyncSocketModeHandler
from slack_bolt.async_app import AsyncApp
from slack_sdk import WebClient


client = WebClient(token=SLACK_BOT_TOKEN)
app = AsyncApp(token=SLACK_BOT_TOKEN)


# This event will be executed when User sends the message
@app.message('')
async def in_message(say, message):
    if 'event' in message['text']:
        response = '22nd Feb, 2023'
        block = []

    await say(text=response, blocks=block)
```

I also tried appending the followup message in the response and update it on ACK but updating doesn't handle the formatting, it treats the message as plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
@app.message('')
async def in_message(say, message):
    if 'event' in message['text']:
        response = '22nd Feb, 2023'
        block = [
                    {
                        "type": "input",
                        "element": {
                            "type": "radio_buttons",
                            "options": [
                                {
                                    "text": {
                                        "type": "plain_text",
                                        "text": "Yes",
                                        "emoji": True
                                    },
                                    "value": "value-0"
                                },
                                {
                                    "text": {
                                        "type": "plain_text",
                                        "text": "No",
                                        "emoji": True
                                    },
                                    "value": "value-1"
                                }
                            ],
                            "action_id": "radio_buttons-action"
                        },
                        "label": {
                            "type": "plain_text",
                            "text": "Does this answer your query?",
                            "emoji": True
                        }
                    }
                ]
        await say(text = response)
        await say(blocks = block)
    else:
        return
```